# CompressorJS - can it convert PNG to JPG?

Tags: reactjs, image, npm

I have a ReactJS application that accepts JPEGs into the workflow. It is needed to also accept PNGs now.

The application does already use [CompressorJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compressorjs) which *does* allow for conversion through some options. I do have some questions though. The goal is to keep the image the same quality but just convert to jpeg.

- quality: A number between 0 and 1. I would like to keep at a 1 so no degradation of the quality of the image.
- mimeType: This could work (changing image/png to image/jpeg) but I do see a difference in the size of the image/blob). When changing mimeType to jpeg, the original image starts at 31 Mb and passing through compressorJS with a quality of 1 (no compression) and a mimeType of jpeg gives me a final size of 16.1 Mb. I'm wondering if this difference is simply compressorJS taking out the alpha channel? Or is it compressing something and losing quality?
- convertSize: PNG files over this value will be converted to JPEGs. I set this to 0 Mb (to convert all PNGs) and a 31 Mb png image (with quality 1 and convertSize 0) turns into a 16.1 Mb JPEG.

I guess I'm wondering if changing the mimeType or convertSize in CompressorJS will cause the image to lose quality when converting a png to a jpg, or is all that data I found to be lost (around 15 Mb) simply the alpha channel? (which I don't care about).

Thank you.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. Also, recommendation requests are not considered in scope for Stackoverflow. It sounds like you're already on track to an answer, so if you boil it down to the specific issue you're having with CompressorJS, you are far more likely to get a good clear answer.

Comment: @Boaz My bad, I have edited my question.